# Wordpress API для плагина

Tags: json, wordpress, api, link

Нужно как-то сделать в плагине, чтобы при переходе по ссылке определенного типа отдавался JSON
где `token` - это код сгенерированный за алгоритмом текущего дня (этот код знает сервер и отправитель)

`method` - это указатель метода для плагина

Ссылка должна получится вида

```
http://domain.ru/wp-api/token/method?postdata=data
```

Я нашел частичный ответ 
[тут](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/184838/how-to-build-an-api-as-a-plugin)

Но как читается эта штука, что это такое, и как ее доработать под меня.

```
 add_rewrite_rule('^wp-api/pugs/?([0-9]+)?/?','index.php?__wp-api=1&pugs=$matches[1]','top');
```

Готов все попробовать сделать сам, но просто объясните как сделать точку входа и чтоб она работала.

Comment: Пролблема-то в чем?

Comment: @tutankhamun в том, что самому очень лень, наверное :)

Comment: "чтобы при переходе по ссылке определенного типа отдавался" - вы имеете ввиду, наверное, не переход пользователя, а запрос от некоего скрипта по этому адресу, в ответ на который приходил бы ответ на ваш запрос?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я верно угадал в комментарии к вашему ответу, что вы на самом деле хотите сделать, то есть два варианта решения данной задачи. Первый - разрабатывать действительно свой `API`, как советуют по вашей ссылке, то есть точку входа для внешних источников запроса. Но это довольно громоздкий вариант, который вряд ли вам нужен.

Второй - просто принимать некоторые запросы и в ответ на них слать некий ответ. В предыдущем ответе другим пользователем вам был дан в целом рабочий для такого решения совет, но, как по мне, более правильно будет поступить описанным ниже образом.

Главным образом потому, что конкретно для асинхронных запросов именно от плагинов, а у вас наверняка такая задача и стоит, именно описанный ниже функционал и подходит (он находится в разделе `Plugin API`), в то время как предложенный другим пользователем вариант - это использование функционала редиректов, что совершенно неверно методологически.

Функционал этот завязан на такой хук: [wp_ajax_(action)](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)) / [wp_ajax_nopriv_(action)](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_nopriv_(action)). Если коротко, то он работает "из коробки" для запросов, сформированных из админки, и с небольшим применением магии работает и для фронта сайта. Подробное описание, как это сделать, есть [тут](https://wp-kama.ru/id_2018/ajax-v-wordpress.html).

Ключевых моментов тут три:

1. Написать функцию, которая будет делать `POST`-запрос на адрес `admin-ajax.php` (адрес будет использоваться в т.ч. и для фронта).
2. Написать колбек, который будет использоваться для ловли вашего запроса и ответа на него, который, в свою очередь, повесить на этот запрос с помощью упомянутого хука `wp_ajax_(my_action)` (часть в скобках меняется на ваше название). Если запрос нужно делать не только из админки, то повесить тот же колбек с помощью хука `wp_ajax_nopriv_(action)`.
3. Добавить на фронт `js`-объект `myajax` (название произвольно), в котором будете хранить адрес вашего эндпоинта, название запроса, ключ для проверки запроса на принадлежность к вашему сайту (`wp_nonce`, токен, но это не про ваш токен, а про токен конкретно для этого функционала) и другие нужные вам на фронте переменные.

Answer (score 3):

Посмотрите в сторону [endpoint'ов](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint) в WordPress. Добавьте свой endpoint, например `json`. И через хук `add_action( 'template_redirect', 'function' );` разбирайте полученный результат.

```
<?php
/**
 * Добавить endpoint
 */
function mihdan_init() {
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'json', EP_ALL );
}
add_action( 'init', 'mihdan_init' );

/**
 * Разобрать запрос и подсунуть JSON
 */
function mihdan_template_redirect() {

    global $wp_query;

    $json = $wp_query->get( 'json' );

    if ( ! $json ) {
        return;
    }

    // Код для получения JSON
    // .....................

    wp_send_json( $json );

}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'mihdan_template_redirect' );
?>
```

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/115510)

Comment: Добавил развернутый ответ, спасибо за уточнение